# SOQL query to find a row with the longest string in a column

Tags: soql, string

I was trying trying to figure out if there is a way in SOQL to select/sort rows in a table with the longest Strings in a selected column.

Something similar to:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM User ORDER BY LENGTH(Name)
```

The closest thing that I've found is the following:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Name LIKE '__________________________'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just `SOQL`? No. You can create a `Name_Length__c` formula though and `ORDER BY` that.

```
LEN(Name)
```

In execute anonymous, you can define an implementation of the [Comparable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) and sort that to get the longest value.

```
class LengthSorter implements Comparable
{
    final User record;
    final Integer length;
    public LengthSorter(User record)
    {
        this.record = record;
        if (String.isBlank(record.Name)) length = 0;
        else length = record.Name.length();
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object instance)
    {
        LengthSorter that = (LengthSorter)instance;
        return this.length - that.length;
    }
}

List<LengthSorter> wrappers = new List<LengthSorter>();
for (User record : [SELECT Name FROM User])
    wrappers.add(new LengthSorter(record));
wrappers.sort();
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but I'm afraid I cannot simply create a new field on Production objects...

Comment: Please elaborate on your use case... you've given us next to nothing to work with. @winter

Comment: Actually, I already solved my problem with the last SOQL query in the topic, but I was curious if there could be additional ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: @winter that only gives you records with a specific length, not necessarily the longest.

Comment: @winter If you're willing to use `Apex` you can do something like the above.